# Extract multiple substrings from Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a horribly formatted column where each cell can contain zero or one or more entries like the following (this one contains two):

`ACTI-U-9754 - Some description MDCF-U-9791 - Some other description`

I need to extract the 11 character strings into a separate column, preferably with a formula. For the cell above it should look like:

ACTI-U-9754
MDCF-U-9791

I haven't found examples that deal with this particular scenario.

Comment: Are the codes always the same format, like xxxx-x-xxxx? Can you post a bigger data sample? Are you open to approaches involving VBA or Power Query?

Comment: Is the center character always a "U"?  How many hyphens are there per "item"?  (just 2 within the code?  Also exactly 1 prefixing the description?  Also potentially any number within the description?)  Are the 1st 4 characters always uppercase letters and the last 4 characters always numbers?

Comment: Yes, the codes are always in the same format: xxxx-x-xxxx

Comment: Is it possible for a `-` to show up in your descriptions?

Comment: The use of VBA depends solely how strict you can predict the format of the codes. You've confirmed the format to be xxxx-x-xxxx, but if you can tell us if the codes always have the -U- in the middle, you don't need regex and no VBA, pure formulas will work.

Comment: And are the codes always of the format xxxx-x-yyyy where the x are non-numeric and the y numeric? A very simple formula-based solution would be available if we could go one further and say that the ONLY substrings of the format zzzz-z-zzzz - where z can be any character - found within a given string will be those you wish to extract.

Comment: Yes, the codes are always in the format CCCC-X-NNNN - <Description>. 
CCCC always contains upper case letters. It is followed by a  dash, then by either an O or a U, then another dash, then 4 numeric characters, a space, a dash, another space and then a free format description (which could conceivably contain dashes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I couldn't think of a simple formula method, however, here is a VBA method using RegEx, in case it is of any use to you. The RegEx pattern assumes codes will always be the same, `4 letters` `-` `1 letter` `-` `4 digits`, of course you can amend as required. If the assumption of letters and digits is incorrect, but the format is always 4-1-4, you could use `.{4}\-.\-.{4}` instead:

[image]

```
Sub GetCodes()
    Dim strPattern: strPattern = "\w{4}\-\w\-\d{4}"   'Pattern to match
    Dim colNumber: colNumber = 1                        'Column number containing strings (In this case, 1, for column A)
    Dim rowCount: rowCount = 1                          'Row number to start from
    Range("B1").Select                                  'Cell to start new column from

    'Create a new RegEx engine instance
    Dim rgx: Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    'Set out RegEx instance to allow Global (More than 1 result per text), MultiLine (Incase there are any carriage returns in the cell), IgnoreCase (Allow both upper and lowercase, which isn't needed with \w but included to be sure) and Pattern, the patter defined above.
    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    'Begin a loop that ends once we hit an empty cell
    Do
        'Get all our RegEx matches and store them in rgxMatches
        Dim rgxMatches: Set rgxMatches = rgx.Execute(Cells(rowCount, colNumber).Value)
        Dim rgxMatch
        'Loop through our matches
        For Each rgxMatch In rgxMatches
            'Write the match into the active cell
            ActiveCell.Value = rgxMatch.Value
            'Go down one row, ready to write the next cell if there is one
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next

        'Increment our row count so the next loop uses the next row
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowCount, colNumber))

    'Clean up after
    Set rgx = Nothing
    Set rgxMatches = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: your code works with only one input cell, however, I think he has many to format. How your code can be used in that case?

Comment: ok, reading deeper I understand your code now. However I still can't agree to post this as an answer for somebody who you aren't sure knows VBA. What about if his data starts at U2, how he will find out what to change?

Comment: Hmm. A fair point, but I'm not sure it makes my answer less valid as an answer. The code does what he wants, and the source is right there if it needs amendments. I addressed the concern that it isn't a formula and may not be what he wants, but it is a starting ground if it comes to it (although personally I find VBA a lot easier to read and understand than some of the mammoth formulas that are required for similar jobs.) When I'm back at my laptop I'll add some comments if that helps.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Please let me know if you believe this is any clearer. Typically I'll make any variables the user may want to edit the first ones defined.